# How to update the README.md file in the angular project?

Tags: angular, git, typescript, github, angular-cli

I updated my angular 6 project to angular 8, and in my `README.md` file having versions for supporting `ng 6` versions Installations. Now I need to update those `previous versions` to `latest versions for supporting ng 8`.
How can I update the `README.md` file with the `git standards`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it will get updated via command line, probably you need to manually update this file

Comment: why don't you just edit it with some text editor , its just a text file though. you could copy the readme file  from a newly generated angular project  or replace its contents . Then commit the changes and push the change to git or you could directly edit it in github

Comment: Do you want to update it with javascript? Without editing the file directly in your editor

Answer (score 0):

You can Edit your README file directly from your GitHub repository.

- Open your GitHub Repository
- Open Readme.md file
- On the top right side, there is a pencil icon which is for an edit of the document.
- And at last, don't forget to commit changes.

So with this simple trick, you can easily update your ReadMe file. Thank you:)